# Prolog Max 2 of the same numbers in a list

Tags: prolog, sudoku

let's get straight to the point.
I'm trying to make a sudoku tectonic solver on my own (not school related). And I've looked for a couple of things to make it work and I came across an issue maybe more people have.

Since it is possible to have a multiple of the same numbers in a row or column for instance if the sudoku is 10 x 10 and u have to fill in number from 1 till 5 an solid solution would be 1,2,1,3,2,3,4,5,4,5. Since all numbers are all used and min and max are 2. Now the question remains, how do i write a predicate that takes in a List and returns a True or false based upon the numbers in the list.

since it isn't possible to use the build in predicate all_distinct but does maybe look like it cuz now instead of all distinct is all distinct if there are 2 of the same numbers, if u follow me.

I tried to do some ugly fixed predicate but it doesn't lead me anywhere.
example.

```
distinct_but_2(A,B,C,D) :-
(   A = B
->  A \= C,
    A \= D),
(   A = C
->  A \= B,
    A \= D),
(   A = D
->  A \= B,
    A \= C),
(   B = A
->  B \= C,
    B \= D),
(   B = C
->  B \= A,
    B \= D),
(   B = D
->  B \= A,
    B \= C),
(   C = A
->  C \= B,
    C \= D),
(   C = B
->  C \= A,
    C \= D),
(   C = D
->  C \= A,
    C \= B),
(   D = A
->  D \= B,
    D \= C),
(   D = B
->  D \= A,
    D \= C),
(   D = C
->  D \= A,
    D \= B).
```

In which im just trying to say if A = B then it is so that it isn't equal to all others, but i still lack that it needs to have that all element have an other element that is the same.

Here an other example i tried

```
    distinct_but_2(A,B,C,D) :-
(isEqual(A,B), isEqual(C,D), notIsEqual(A,C), notIsEqual(A,D));
(isEqual(A,C), isEqual(B,D), notIsEqual(A,B), notIsEqual(A,D));
(isEqual(A,D), isEqual(B,C), notIsEqual(A,B), notIsEqual(A,C)).
```

isEqual(A,B) :-
    A = B.

notIsEqual(A,B) :-
    A \= B.

The result of the query distinct_but_2(1,1,2,2).
would be true, but it says it has an other solution as well. that it's false. And i just quite can't get why.

So the final question is, is it possible to make a predicate that checks for a list if all elements have min and max one element that is the same.

*Note that I have not made a predicate that takes in a list since i was trying to make it work for 4 elements, but i should take in a list.

Comment: *...but it says it has an other solution as well. that it's false*. Not exactly. In your case, your code leaves a *choice point*. That means Prolog has other options to explore before it determines whether there are any more solutions. After the first solution, it prompts you to search for them. if it finds no more, it outputs false.

Comment: @lurker Oh yeah i forgot about that part, you are completely right thank you for the note :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say which Prolog system you are using, but it seems you are looking for something like `global_cardinality/{2,3}`, as SWI has it: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=global_cardinality/3

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

two_each(Numbers, Vars) :-
    length(Numbers, Len),
    Len2 #= 2*Len,
    length(Vars, Len2),
    bagof(X-2, member(X, Numbers), Pairs),
    global_cardinality(Vars, Pairs).
```

query:

```
?- two_each([1,2,3], Vars), label(Vars).
Vars = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] ;
Vars = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3] ;
Vars = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
```

query with Sudoku hints:

```
?- two_each([1,2,3], Vars), Vars=[_,3,_,1,1,_], label(Vars).
Vars = [2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3] ;
Vars = [2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2] ;
Vars = [3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2].
```

Comment: Dear @firefrorfiddle I indeed did not mention which Prolog system I was using. Sorry it's a new language to me and I didn't know there were multiple variants out there. And what you thought I seemed to be looking for was indd global_cardinality. I'm sorry that I couldn't find it on my own. I wasn't aware this was a thing and I really tried looking for it. With your assistance and predicate two_each I completed my Program, It is very ugly since I'm not familiar with recursion in Prolog yet, Thus I had to specify all the things i wanted, but it worked and now my Sudoku Tectonic is solved. Thanku

Comment: @HiddeGoossens I'm happy to hear. :-) Feel free to give me the solve-tick to my answer.

Comment: what do u mean with the Feel free to give the solve-tick to my answer? not really sure what u mean by it :D

Comment: aaah sorry new to posting questions on here (done).